# How can I fill a heading with a rule in KOMA classes?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, rules

I am customizing `section` headings for `scrartcl` and wanted to try adding a rule after the section title filling the line.

As suggested in section **12.8.** of the KOMA manual, instead of drawing the rule inside `\AddtoDoHook` directly, I am creating a command with an empty argument to avoid problems with the parameter introduced by `\ExecuteDoHook`. My attempt at doing this:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
    \usepackage{xhfill}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

%% ----------------------------------------
%%  The issue:
    \newcommand{\hfilllinegobble}[1]{\xrfill[0.4ex]{1.5pt}}
    \AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\hfilllinegobble}


\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

When I try to run this, there is no output and I get the following error message, and I do not know what a 'glue' is or how to repair one.

> Leaders not followed by proper glue. \blinddocument

However, I am using a similar method for adding a line below chapter headings in `scrbook`, which works perfectly fine:

```latex
\newcommand{\headinglinegobble}[1]{\vspace*{-1ex}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}} 

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/chapter}{\headinglinegobble}
```

How can I modify the section head without messing up the 'glue'? Are there better ways of customizing KOMA-headings in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `\@@par` after the title and before `\ExecuteDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}` in the source code. Therefore you have to add a `\leavevmode` and the line will be below of the section title:

```latex
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\leavevmode\hfilllinegobble}
```

So I would suggest to redefine `\sectionlinesformat`, eg.:

```latex
\newcommand*{\hfilllinegobble}{\xrfill[0.4ex]{1.5pt}}
\newcommand*\originalsectionlinesformat{}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
   \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4\Ifstr{#1}{section}{ \hfilllinegobble}{}}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

%% ----------------------------------------
%%  The issue:
\newcommand*{\hfilllinegobble}{\xrfill[0.4ex]{1.5pt}}
\newcommand*\originalsectionlinesformat{}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
   \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4\Ifstr{#1}{section}{ \hfilllinegobble}{}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still need to think about why and how this works, but it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: `\sectionlinesformat` etc. is explained in section 21.8. of the KOMA-Script manual.